# How do I debug JavaScript written within a script tag in the HTML

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

I am attempting to debug external JavaScript within a  tag on an iframe on a website that I do not have access to the source code.  I am able to debug all of the javascript files directly but not the javascript embedded within the HTML.

I have attempted to search for the code within the sources tab and I am unable to come up with it.  I have attempted to use firefox developer edition as well as chrome dev tools

issue I am trying to debug:

```
<iframe>
   <html>
     <head>
       <script> javascript I want to debug </script>
     <body>
     </body>
   </html>
</iframe>

I would like to place breakpoints anywhere within the code to debug it.
```

Answer (score 4):

In Chrome's devtools:

1. Open the **Sources** tab
2. Click the **Show Navigator** icon if the navigator isn't already showing

   [image]
3. Find the name of the frame's HTML file in the navigator tree

   [image]
4. Expand it, which will show the domain the frame is from, then expand it again to find frame's HTML file (again)

   [image]
5. Click on that file to see its source

   [image]
6. Within the script, click in the line number gutter to the right of the line where you want to set a breakpoint

   [image]

Comment: well I am attempting to debug an appscripts iframe and I am unable to find the code this way, Maybe it is being built dynamically or there is something the way they sandbox the iframes.

Answer (score 0):

Just a picture to visualize what Crowder wrote above. 
[image: obove is the correct answer]

Comment: I've added step-by-step pictures now. (BTW, to improve/add to an answer, it's perfectly fine to use "edit" on it, even if it's someone else's answer. :-) )

Comment: Oh, thank you :) didn´t realize that I have this option. I´ll remember it for the next time.